# backgroundTimeRemaining returns (35791394 mins)?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I'm using beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler in my application. my understanding the max time given for background application to finish work is 10 minutes, but what i got when I printed the value of backgroundTimeRemaining is (35791394 mins)

```
NSTimeInterval timeLeft = [UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining;
    NSLog(@"Background time remaining2222: %.0f seconds (%d mins)", timeLeft, (int)timeLeft / 60);
```

is this normal, or it seems I did something wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 NSLog(@"Background time remaining: %f seconds (%d mins)", timeLeft, (int)(timeLeft / 60));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
NSLog(@"Background time remaining2222: %.0f seconds (%d mins)", timeLeft, (int)(timeLeft / 60) );
```

In your code timeLeft is being changed to an int BEFORE dividing, not after.